# Cannot setState() with Firebase database listener

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build a mini-game with rooms. When I try to retrieve room information from my firebase realtime database, I used database.ref().on() function to listen on any data changes and setting my state according to the change. Here is what the code looks like:

```
export default class Room extends Component {
  state = {
    room: null,
    username: "sdff",
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const roomId = this.props.location.pathname;
    app()
      .database()
      .ref(`/rooms${roomId}`)
      .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ room: data });
        this.setState({ room: "hello" });
      });
  }
```

When I do console.log(data), I actually do see that data contains all information that I want. However, this.setState is not working, which causes the page failing to render since lots of the information from state is used in render(). Even if I set room to "hello", as shown in the last statement of the code snippet, it still fails to set state. I'm wondering if it's because render() is called before the data is successfully retrieved? If so, how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) instead.

As React official docs say:

> This method is a good place to set up any subscriptions

Also, don't forget to end the subscription on **componentWillUnmount()**